# Как сделать быстрый доступ к директории в командной строке? (OS X)

Tags: macos, cmd

Как сделать быстрый доступ к директории в CMD (OS X)?
К примеру, у меня есть папка с таким адресом:

`/Users/Name/Documents/App`

Но я не хочу каждый раз для перехода в эту директорию прописывать весь адрес:

`cd /Users/Name/Documents/App`

Как можно забиндить, чтобы обращаться по команде:
`cd APP` или просто `APP`?

Comment: Ну, можно записать последовательность команд в файл и запускать его одним кликом. Но почему вас не устраивает проход по истории cmd (кнопка 'вверх')? Плюс быстро скопировать полный путь до папки можно через простой drag&drop из finder.

Comment: "Плюс быстро скопировать полный путь до папки можно через простой drag&drop из finder." - такой вариант подходит, спасибо.